# Analog of convolution theorem for rotation (rather than translation) of coordinates?

Tags: fourier-transform, rotations, convolution

According to [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) convolution between two functions $f(r), g(r)$ in real space (e.g. 2D,3D) can be calculated as product of Fourier images.

Convolution $(f*g)(\vec R) = \int_{\vec r} f(\vec r)g(\vec R-\vec r)$ is an integral over product of a function $f(\vec r)$ and a flipped **translation** of function $g(\vec R-\vec r)$.

I would like something similar for **rotation**: $(f \circ g)(\alpha) = \int_{\vec r} f(\vec r)g( \hat R(\alpha).\vec r)$

Where $R(\alpha)$ is a rotation matrix which rotates coordinate $r$ by angle $\alpha$.

E.g. in 2D space:

$$
\hat R(\alpha) = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\alpha) -\sin(\alpha) \\
    \sin(\alpha) \cos(\alpha)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

EDIT: There is a paper about using [FFT to rotate images](http://nontrivialzeros.net/KGL_Papers/27_Rotation_Paper_1997_qualityscan_OCR.pdf), but I'm not quite sure how to apply it to evaluation of rotational-convolution

Comment: I think your definition of convolution is wrong, it reduces to $(f*g)(r) = f(r)\int g$. The same problem exists in your "rotational convolution" definition, so it's hard to extrapolate what your actually intend.

Comment: Aha, I see. It was really quite crucial to realize that result $(f \circ g )(\alpha)$ is function of Alpha. I corrected it now.

Comment: If you define $g_\alpha(\vec r) = g(\hat R(\alpha)\cdot \vec r)$ then it turns into cross-correlation at $\vec R=\mathbf 0$, i.e. $(f\circ g)(\alpha) = (f\star g_\alpha)(\mathbf 0)$. But if you're looking for the spectrum of $f\circ g$ along $\alpha$ then this finding does not really help.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, in the 2D case you could rewrite the integral in polar coordinates as

$$\int_\rho\int_\theta f(\rho,\theta)g(\rho,\theta+\alpha)\rho\,d\rho\,d\theta$$ and see this as an integral of convolutions over $\theta$,

$$\int_\rho f(\rho)\star g(\rho)\,\rho\,d\rho$$

Comment: OK you are right, but I'm not sure now, if that is useful to me, since I have data sampled on regular rectangular grid and I do FFT. If I would transform them to polar grid and do FFT in polar coordinates I think it would mess things up.

Comment: @ProkopHapala: you have no choice. Rotating the grid will mess things up.

Comment: A polar grid also has a center. The distance between adjacent points changes nonuniformly.